# LINKS with flutter_html

Tags: html, json, flutter

JSON is code

```
<p>Iscrizioni aperte fino al 10 Ottobre. La scuola si riserver&agrave; di accettare o meno iscrizioni arrivate dopo tale data.<br />Per info o iscrizione&nbsp;<strong>SCRIVI</strong> A <a href="mailto:xxx@xxxx.it">xxx@xxx.it</a> o <strong>CHIAMA</strong> IL <a href="tel:+xxxxxxxx">xxxxxx</a></p>
```

[YOGA CERTIFICATA DI ALMENO UN ANNO](https://www.google.it)

Work, on flutter I have install "flutter_html", is good and work but don't work only the links..why?